# How to reduce time to render large surface data in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es-2.0, visualization

I am currently working on a project that renders large oil-wells and sub-surface data on to the android tablet using OpenGL ES 2.0.

The data comes in from a restful call made by the client (Tablet) to the server. I need to render two types of data. One being a set of vertices where I just join all the vertices (Well rendering) and the other is the subsurface rendering where each surface has huge triangle-data associated with them.

I was able to reduce the size of the well by approximating the next point and constructing the data that is to be sent to the client. But this cannot be done to the surface data as each and every triangle is important to get the triangles joined and form the surface.

I would appreciate if you guys suggest an approach to either reduce the data from the server or to reduce the time taken to render such a huge data effectively.

Answer (score 1):

the way you can handle such complex mesh really depends on the scope of your project. Unfortunately there is no much we can say based on the provided inputs and the activity itself is not an easy task.

Usually when the mesh is very complex a typical approach to make the rendering process fast is to adopt dynamic Level Of Details (in programming terminology LOD).

The idea is to render "distant" meshes with a very low LOD (and therefore having a much lower number of vertices to be rendered) and there replace the mesh with an higher resolution every time the camera approaches the mesh's details.

This is a technique very used in computer games, for instance when a terrain needs to be rendered. When the player is in a particular sector of the MAP, the mesh of that sector is in High level of detail, the others are in low detail. As soon as the player moves, the different sectors become in "high resolution" (allow me the term).

It is not an easy way to do it but it works in many many situations.

In this gamasutra article, there are plenty of information on how this technique works:

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131596/realtime_dynamic_level_of_detail_.php?print=1

The idea, in your case, would be to take the mesh provided by the web service and handle it as the HD version of the mesh. Then (particularly if the mesh is composed by different objects), apply a triangular mesh simplification algorithm to create LD meshes of the same objects. An example on the way you could proceed is well described here:

http://herakles.zcu.cz/~skala/PUBL/PUBL_2002/2002_Mesh-Simplification-ICCS2002.pdf

I hope to have helped in some way.

Cheers
Maurizio